# How do I enable `cookie-session` with Firebase

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I have an issue with `cookie-session` when using Firebase Functions in production. I have a React app in Firebase Hosting, and an Express app in Functions (that I'm using as my API), and I've created a template repo that demonstrates this setup for all to see (https://github.com/cjmyles/firebase-react-express).

I'm making fetch calls from the React app to `/api/*` (notice the lack of a fully qualified url) and the request is proxied to the API in development mode using the `proxy` config value in `package.json`; and proxied to the API in production using the `rewrites` config value in `firebase.json`.

This works fine until I start to use sessions. I have some code that mimics a login request using PassportJS where the user information is stored in the session, and this works in development mode, but not in production. I have a feeling it's something to do with the cookies. I'm using `cookie-session` in my express app and I've made sure that the `secure` flag is set to `true` in production (as it's served over https), but I think the cookie isn't being passed to the API properly when the request is proxied via the Firebase `rewrites`.

Do I need to add something to `firebase.json` to enable `cookie-session` in production?

Comment: Did you manage to resolve your issue? I'm with the same problem now.

Comment: Yes, I used the "__session" cookie which can be set using `res.cookie` and retrieved using `req.cookies` in your Express middleware, after the npm module `cookie-parser` has been initialized. I've accepted Rafael's answer below which covers the solution in more detail. I can provide a full answer if required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When requests are proxied using the rewrite rules for firebase hosting, the only cookie permitted is `__session`.

This is documented in https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/manage-cache#using_cookies.

Answer (score -1):

You will definitely get your query resolved [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-cookies).

Comment: Any idea how I'd get that to work with passport js? The documentation looks like it requires an `idToken` obtained from executing the `signInWithEmailAndPassword` function which I won't be doing, as I have passport js set up with Facebook.